# Accessing global variable in multiple qml files in blackberry cascades 10

Tags: javascript, c++, blackberry, qml, blackberry-cascades

I have created a js file for storing constants inside assets/Model/constants.js I had a view inside assets/homeview.qml. This homeview.qml imports

```
import "Model/constants.js" as Global
```

and I could access `Global.myConstant` with no error.

Now I moved the homeview.qml inside a folder. assets/Views/homeview.qml and changed the import location to

```
import "/Model/constants.js" as Global
```

but now `Global.myConstant` shows unknown variable myConstant error. Is there something else I need to do when I move file inside a folder?

Comment: it looks like you only added / before the path in you example. Also what exactli the file name - constant.js or constants.js?

Comment: file name is constants.js sorry for the typo in the question, yes I only added /, as when I moved the view to folder it showed error that import folder does not exist, adding / seemed to fix that. But I think the variables in the file still cant be accessed. Is there anything more I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your import should work.

```
import "/Model/constants.js" as Global
```

Nevertheless, there is another way to import the file.

```
import "../Model/constants.js" as Global
```

This is a relative path to the file. At first you go one directory up and then go into the Model directory containing the constants.js file.